# Is there a method to find the min, max of a Tensorflow/Keras layer input during training?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

Is there an option to find the min, max range of the input, of a Keras/Tensorflow layer where the output of the min, max range calculation is a float?

E.g. I want to know this range for the tf.fake_quant_with_min_max_args() function, where min, max should be a float, instead of a tensor.

I do this for the weights as follows inside my custom Keras layer which works perfect:

```
w_max = tf.keras.backend.eval(tf.math.reduce_max(self.weights))
w_min = tf.keras.backend.eval(tf.math.reduce_min(self.weights))
self.weights= tf.quantization.fake_quant_with_min_max_args(self.weights, min=w_min, max=w_max)
```

This works (the output is a float), because the weights are initialized when a layer is created.

Now I want to do something similar, but with the input of a layer. This doesn't work, as the output of the min, max is a Tensor, I assume this is because the input is a placeholder and the values are not known when the layer is built.

Is there an option/method/workaround to still find the min, max of the layer input such that it can be used for the tf.quantization.fake_quant_with_min_max_args() function? E.g. during building set the min, max to a default value, but during training, interference, or when there is data feed to the input, it calculates the min, max as float?